# Selecting a line with mouse stopped working

Tags: windows-10, mouse

My question is about my laptop which is running Windows 10 OS. I am using battery powered Bluetooth mouse and keyboard. Everything was fine till last week, but suddenly I started experiencing issues while doing something with my mouse. Mainly, I am experiencing below mentioned 3 issues -

1. When I select a line/paragraph using my mouse, it starts but then breaks at one point then again starts from another point. That means I am unable to select a whole paragraph. I need to try many times to simply select a paragraph.
2. Right click is not working in one go. I need to try 3-4 times to get options which come on right click.
3. Left click some time behaves as if I clicked 2 times.

Any help please?

Comment: Many modern computer mice have batteries. Did you change the batteries?   Can you update the mouse driver?

Comment: Thanks. Updated my question. Yes I changed the battery but this didn't solve the issue. On updating the driver,  I get a message - 'You have latest driver'.

Answer (score 1):

As I'm dealing with those issues on daily basis I'd do the following to understand the issue and possibly fix it.

1. You mentioned that you're using laptop. All of the actions you described can be done with using built-in touchpad (try this to narrow down the issue to hardware instead of software). If you don't experience any of the issues with touchpad- it's hardware issue.
2. If it's an hardware issue try using different mouse just to see if anything changes.
3. Apart from that only thing I can think of is: Go to Settings > Devices > Mouse > Additional Mouse Options.

There you can check if you have ClickLock enabled as this can mess up selecting part of your question ( I usually leave this disabled).

Let me know if any of this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I recently experienced problems 1 and 3 from your description, but I was not having any trouble with right-clicking.

To troubleshoot, I switched the mouse's primary and secondary buttons in Control Panel > Mouse Properties. Left button clicks continued to be problematic, but left-click *functions* like selecting text, etc. (which were now being performed using the mouse's right button), all worked properly.

This pretty much confirmed that the issue was a physical problem with the mouse's left-click switch, so I replaced the mouse and haven't had any further trouble.

It sounds like both switches in your mouse might be failing.